# Git appears to have hijacked my windows command prompt

Tags: windows, git

I installed Git for windows XP, and for some reason I couldn't get it to work. It threw and error code  that showed it was looking for a network drive (drive Z:\ instead of the local drive C:).  I got tired of fooling with it and decided to try the bash that came with GIT.  Well, I got into the command prompt and saw the following:

```
Z:\[my name]>
```

I tried

```
Z:\[My name]>cd C:\
```

and all I got was a return back to the same prompt.  It didn't actually switch directories.  So, I tried

```
Z:\[My name]>cd D:\
```

which failed because the D drive does not exist.  But, trying to switch to the C drive doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't do anything. I can't access my c drive via the command prompt any more at all.

A little bit confused, I uninstalled Git.  Now, after rebooting, I still cannot access the C drive through the command prompt, and it defaults to the Z drive instead.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something stepped in and changed your home directory settings. Type `echo %USERPROFILE%` and you'll probably see your Z: drive set. Check your Environment Variables settings to change it back if you need.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction.  Apparently you can also type set in the command prompt to find all the environmental variables (that aren't necessarily listed in environmental variables in my computer).  I just wish I could use Ubuntu for my work OS.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, try typing C:
(ie no command, just the drive letter to switch to)

Comment: Thank you, that got me back to the C: drive, but the default is still the Z drive.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
Z:\[MyName]>PROMPT $p$g
```

Probably wrong but it is the solution to the literal interpretation of hijacked my prompt.

Comment: OK, useless to you. If you want to understand, try PROMPT "What is thy bidding? "